# View the http header of response

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiwebview

When working with UIWebViews, is there a way to capture a request (all GET requests - also for the page's content/images etc.) on the way so that I can examine the request/response headers (without resolving to wireshark)?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the delegate of the webview and capture the request by function below.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

Then exam the request header inside the request object.

Comment: Above method shows header field of request. Can i lookup inside response's header fields?